# Firebase and Completion handler

Tags: swift, firebase

Im currently using firebase to retrieve user info. once I receive the data I want to use the data outside of all closure the I create a completion block the problem is that I can not add the completion variable to the result because the result is inside another closure. How can fix this problem. Thank you in advance for the help.

```
 func userInfo(userId:String,completion:(result:String)->Void){


        fireBaseAPI().childRef("version_one/frontEnd/users/\(fireBaseAPI().currentUserId()!)/email").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in

            let email = snapshot.value as! String

            //this is incorrect because it is inside a firebase closure how can I make it work I know i have it outside the closure but i will not be able to retrieve the info from firebase
            result = email

        })




    }
```

Comment: Be more clear as to what you want, also provide with more info as to what is `fireBaseAPI()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i could understand your problem ::---

You want to send the emailID of your user in the **completionBlock:** once retrieved, But i still don't have any idea to what `fireBaseAPI()` is :-

```
func userInfo(userId:String,completion:((result:String)->Void){
fireBaseAPI().childRef("version_one/frontEnd/users/\(fireBaseAPI().currentUserId()!)/email").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in

        let email = snapshot.value as! String
        completion(result:email)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a variable in your class (outside of the closure) and then store the `snapshot.value` result in that variable like this:

**EDIT**

```
var emailResult: String?

func getUserEmail {
    fireBaseAPI().child("version_one/frontEnd/users/\(fireBaseAPI().currentUserId()!)/email").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
        let email = snapshot.value as! String
        self.emailResult = email
    })
}
```

Comment: that result will always come back nil because the the variable is set it is inside of the closure that is the reason i had to make a completion handler

Comment: I just edited my answer. I don't know what the rest of your class looks like but could you do something like what I wrote above? Why do you need to pass in `userId:String` in your original `userInfo` method since you're calling `fireBaseAPI().currentUserId()` to get the user ID? And why do you need to add a completion handler on top of the Firebase closure `withBlock`?

Comment: Hey iOSMoonSand. This will indeed ensure that the email result is available outside of `getUserEmail()`. Firebase loads the data asynchronously, so the callback may be invoked (much) later. Even "worse": Firebase will continue to synchronize the data, so the email result may change over time. The main problem with your code is to know **when** email result is available and (even more difficult) when it is updated. That's why Dravidian's approach with a callback (while initially less intuitive) is more idiomatic for these calls.